# how can a .tiff file be input to Matlab vision.VideoFileReader?

Tags: matlab, video, tiff, matlab-cvst

I have a .tiff video file and want to input it into my Matlab script.
But vision.VideoFileReader supports only .mpeg .mp2 .mpg .m4v but NOT .tiff.

Does Matlab have a function that converts .tiff to a format readable by vision.VideoFileReader?

Comment: TIFF is a still image format. Do you have a multi-layered TIFF or a folder full of separate frames?

Comment: Yes.  It is the output from a FLIR camera.

Comment: Yes what? Multi-Tiff of separate frames? Plus what OS are you working with? Supported file types seem to [differ](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.videofilereader-class.html?refresh=true) depending on the platform

Comment: Sorry -- multi-page .tiff file, where each page is a single frame.  Windows-7 Pro 64-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `imread`.

```
img = imread('image.tif', i);
```

will read the i-th image from a multi-image TIFF file.